# How does UA Curse of the Sea work with forced movement?

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, unearthed-arcana, forced-movement, cantrips

I'm looking at [Sea Sorcery: Curse of the Sea](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/26_UASorcererUA020617s.pdf) (Unearthed Arcana).

With the Curse of the Sea forced Movement Option with Lightning lure would it fling the target behind me?

Also does Infestation work with Forced Movement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## In a straight line towards you

The question here is whether or not **Towards You** ends at you, or if it continues past you.

### You are the endpoint (I believe this is the intent)

Lightning Lure (SCAG 143) states with my emphasis:

> ...be pulled **up to** 10 feet in a straight line **toward you**.

The specific interpretation of that may be table dependent, but the intent is to draw a creature closer to you. If it goes past you, it is no longer moving towards you - it is moving away from you.

If the creature is 10' away and you use the curse for Movement along with Lightning Lure, it would move **up to 25 feet in straight line toward you**. Once it reached you, it would stop - just like it would if it was 5' away and you cast it normally. The phrase **up to** is your limiting factor.

### Infestation is forced movement and it would apply

[Infestation](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-Starter-Spells.pdf) States:

> If the target takes    any of  that    damage,
> the target  moves   5   feet    in  a   random  direction.

That is forced movement, and the Curse would apply.